# MS Word header and footer for page 1 spans 2 pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

This is is Word 2007. I picked up a doco that someone else started, and it has the header and footer for page one spanning 2 pages. I want to treat the first page differently, but it actually treats the first *and second* page differently. I have tried selecting or un-selecting link to previous. I have also tried creating and removing sections. Problem is I can't find where in the menu it extends Page 1 to be across two pages.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Please consider using a question mark to denote a question. I've tried to answer this to the best I could with the question in it's current state

Answer (score 2):

I just googled it... [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/insert-headers-and-footers-HP001226486.aspx#BM2)

1. On the first page of the document, double click the header or footer area.
2. Under Header & Footer Tools, on the Design tab, in the Options group, select the Different First Page check box.

It's unclear exactly what your asking but from what I can tell this isn't something your doing